# identify the document when computing the tfidf with scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

hi i wanna see the tfidf of each term for each document by using scikit :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os,glob

pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer())])

corpus = []
os.chdir("/home/yougha/workspace/RecPrec/corpusH_test")
for file in glob.glob("*.ann"):
    f=open(file,'r').read().splitlines()
    corpus.append(str(' '.join(f)))



X = pipeline.fit_transform(corpus)
vec = pipeline.named_steps['tfidf']
features = vec.get_feature_names()
```

the problem is that  i get this result set:

```
(0, 3014)   0.0377805822964
(0, 408)    0.0350786341362
(0, 1674)   0.0315760656866
(0, 2894)   0.0684834084489
(0, 414)    0.0702763812732
(0, 5435)   0.259268251165
(0, 4931)   0.0386510244744
(0, 5878)   0.0625452304837
(0, 4129)   0.0515443519972
(0, 867)    0.0537265899836
(0, 847)    0.0550074477291
(0, 5296)   0.046810389078
```

I absolutely don't know what to do with that ,

Is it possible to have something like that

```
Name of Doc |word1 |word2 |word3
doc1        |0.4   |0.2   |0.3
```

what i wanna do is to identify the document and printing the tfidf for each word occuring in this document.

Answer (score 0):

## What you see

```
(0, 3014)   0.0377805822964
(0, 408)    0.0350786341362
(0, 1674)   0.0315760656866
(0, 2894)   0.0684834084489
```

That is *spare matrix*. The first column identifies point coordinates in a matrix with second column identifying value of the point.

So

```
(0, 3014)   0.0377805822964
```

means  that

```
X[0, 3014] = 0.0377805822964
```

## How to get feature values

If you want to see feature weight in a table view, you can convert spare matrix to `NumPy` `ndarray`

```
x_array = X.toarray()
```

But be ready to see almost empty matrix ion this case.

I believe more useful presentation is features of each document (ordered)

```
features_of_docs = pipeline.inverse_transform(X)
```

Comment: I would recommend against converting a sparse matrix of word features to an array. It is easy to end up with unnecesarily huge matrices.

Comment: @KT., I agree if we are talking about processing. But arrays more verbose when printed

Answer (score 0):

Although Lol4to has offered a decent answer above, I think it is important to note that `X` is a sparse matrix, and to "extract" the features from it, rather than converting it to a full array you should probably do something like the following:

```
files = glob.glob("*.ann")
X = X.to_csr()

for i, row in enumerate(X):
    print("Document %s" % files[i])
    print("------------------------")
    for i, val in zip(row.indices, row.data):
        print("   %s: %f" % (features[i], val))
```